# Use Amazon Kinesis Firehose to aggregate data by the same key

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a use case where I want to aggregate data based on a specific key in order to batch process them after a specific period of time.

The key value is not known before hand, but I want all the records with Key `A` to be returned from the stream together, and all the records with Key `B` to be returned from the stream together and so on.

Is it possible to do this with AWS Kinesis firehose custom partitioning?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Kinesis Firehose doesn't support a custom partitioning key.

Other available options:

1. If the distribution of the keys is low create a firehose per key.
2. Send data to Kinesis Data Stream using the partition key, connect the stream to AWS Lambda with Custom Batch Window (up to 300 sec), This way you can aggregate the stream.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The keys are not known beforehand and vary widely. Would Kinesis Analytics custom sink nodes work for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

As @Uri also mentioned, Kinesis Firehose doesn't support the Custom partitioning. If you want to aggregate data on a custom key level, there is an option to use Glue ETL jobs.

You can offload your data from Kinesis Firehose to the S3 buckets. That data layer can act as raw data layer. On top of that, you can develop some `Glue ETL pipelines` where data can be reorganized and partitioned using custom attributes. Also, it will allow you to perform data cleansing if you want to do that.

I had the similar scenario and handled by writing Glue ETL jobs.